# Symfony Controller executed multiple Time

Tags: symfony, events, event-listener

When a user access to my page, i dispatch an *visitedEvent* in my showAction of my controller.
This event must increment a view counter in my database.

My problem is that my controller seem to be called multiple times (two times) to show my page. My counter is always incremented twice !

I'm certain that my event is only dispatched here (its not dispatch in an other controller)

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM ???**
how can i create a counter who is incremented only once time ?!

Think's

Comment: Maybe you're inadvertently loading the page twice? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: is your show page loaded after a login?  I would use the profiler and look at the last 10 requests when testing to see what controllers are called.

Comment: Maybe you're rendering some other action from this controller in template?

Comment: Yes @KarolWojciechowski, After many search problem seem to come from my view show.html.twig. But this view never call my controller showAction ! My view call a different sub-controller with this line `{% render(controller("NsiDiscussionBundle:Commentaire:liste", {'id':entity.discussion.id })) %}` but this controller doesn't contain any database insert ! So Why my view entity is inserted twice ?!!! Think's

Answer (score 1):

After many search, I've found in my view an image with `src="#"`witch cause this issue.

Think's all for your help !

Comment: For me it was a css background image.  `background-image: url();`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should create an service that handles this, saving your visitor data and call it simple in your controller:

```
$this->container->get('my.tracking.service')->storeThisVisit($params);
```

Comment: The problem is same with a service