# Embedded Twig controllers cause kernel.request events to fire multiple times

Tags: events, symfony, twig-extension

In my Symfony project, I've come across a bizarre problem with `kernel.request` [event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html) firing multiple times when [embedded Twig controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers) are used.

In my custom event listener I have an event listener that sends a redirect response if a certain condition exists (an expired password in this case). In order to prevent a redirect loop I checked if we were already on the page:

```
if ($event->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'user_change_password') {
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_change_password'));
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

But that didn't stop the redirect loops. Until I added logging, I had no idea that an embedded controller would fire the `kernel.request` event (it's obvious in hindsight, since these embedded controllers work by sending a "sub-request"). I have a single embedded controller in by base twig template that checks for any alert messages and displays them.

**Given the above**, how can I

1. be able to insert dynamic content into a base template (that all other templates extend), AND
2. not have `kernel.request` event listeners fire multiple times.

Even though Symfony suggests inserting that dynamic content into base templates using embedded controllers, is this considered bad practice?

Would it be better to create a [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) to solve this problem? From what I've seen, Twig extensions are generally only used for simple stuff, like the `price` example in the cookbook, though I can't see why it wouldn't work for more complex, database-connected things. I'm just not sure on how to do that.

Examples are appreciated.

---

Possible related?: [Symfony Controller executed multiple Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364349/symfony-controller-executed-multiple-time)

Comment: kernel.request is fired for each request, this includes subrequests such as {{ render(controller('...')) }}

Comment: That right, that's what I said. I was trying to find a solution to the problem I explained above, which xabbuh kindly provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the redirection only if the event listener is executed for the master request:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

// ...

if ($event->isMasterRequest() && $event->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'user_change_password') {
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_change_password'));
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

If you are still bound to Symfony 2.3, you can use the `getRequestType()` method compare its return value with the `MASTER_REQUEST` constant from the `HttpKernelInterface` (that's what `isMasterRequest()` does internally):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

// ...

if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType() && $event->getRequest()->get('_route') != 'user_change_password') {
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_change_password'));
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That's the sort of solution that I like: quick and easy. Thank you! One thing though: the method has apparently been renamed to `$event->getRequestType()` in Symfony3. Also, the full namespace (for the `use` statement) is `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface`.

Comment: I was poking into the source, and I found an easier way. There's an event method called `isMasterRequest()` that does the exact requestType comparison in the answer. Not sure when this was added to Symfony, but it's a preferred solution.

Comment: You are right. The method was introduced in Symfony 2.4. I updated my answer again for anyone stumbling over this in the future.